# Can't detect exit of cmd command from c# correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, cmd

I execute cmd command by this code, it works fine on most of the commands like ver, cd ... but on commands like netstat or a `dir` on folder with many files, that need more time to execute, it cannot detect that command finished.

I can use timeout but I want to know why it can't detect end of netstat command

```
string results="";
string command = @"dir c:\windows";
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();

results = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); //<-Move here

proc.WaitForExit();

//results = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); //Moved

Console.WriteLine(results);
```

**Fix:**
I move reading results (results = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();) and it solve the problem.

Comment: netstat is an exe. no need to start it via cmd. maybe that helps you to read to read the output

Answer (score 0):

With your code I couldn't reproduce the problem:

[image]

What you're saying isn't possible, using [Process.WaitForExit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx):

> Instructs the Process component to wait indefinitely for the associated process to exit.

---

**Edit 1:**

Even using `dir c:\Windows` (which took over a minute) I was unable to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you have a few connection it works fine, but if you have many connection it dosn't work. you can use another command like string command = @"dir c:\windows";   it have same problem because the fies in windows dire are much.

Comment: Which version of .net and OS you use?

Comment: Windows 7, .net 4.7